# Add a picture beside this Google Maps map

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a picture beside this Google Maps map: https://i.stack.imgur.com/87kp3.jpg but I'm not sure how, here is my code:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.flex-container>div {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="contact-us" id="contact-section">
  <div class="contact-us-bgimage grid-margin">
    <div class="pb-4">
      <h4 class="px-3 px-md-0 m-0" data-aos="fade-down">¿Tiene alguna duda?</h4>
      <h4 class="pt-1" data-aos="fade-down"> ឵឵ </h4>
    </div>
    <div data-aos="fade-up">
      <button class="btn btn-rounded btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Contáctanos</a>
          </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3901.165195727537!2d-77.02086168507019!3d-12.100840946203745!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x9105c87176d57413%3A0x91785bfebf4bb5dc!2sAv.%20Rep%C3%BAblica%20de%20Panam%C3%A1%203635%2C%20San%20Isidro%2015036!5e0!3m2!1sen!2spe!4v1652844514162!5m2!1sen!2spe"
      width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
    <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/972188609815912449/976353955137343548/final_edificio.png" height="450" alt="">
  </div>
</section>
```

I want the picture right here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pifAJ.jpg Hopefully someone can help me out, thanks!

Comment: When I run the code, I'm not getting the same error. It seems to line up for me.

Comment: May you please upload a screenshot? Because it's not working for me...

Answer (score 0):

Use `justify-content: space-around;` on the `flex-container`.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-container>div {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="contact-us" id="contact-section">
  <div class="contact-us-bgimage grid-margin">
    <div class="pb-4">
      <h4 class="px-3 px-md-0 m-0" data-aos="fade-down">¿Tiene alguna duda?</h4>
      <h4 class="pt-1" data-aos="fade-down"> ឵឵ </h4>
    </div>
    <div data-aos="fade-up">
      <button class="btn btn-rounded btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Contáctanos</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3901.165195727537!2d-77.02086168507019!3d-12.100840946203745!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x9105c87176d57413%3A0x91785bfebf4bb5dc!2sAv.%20Rep%C3%BAblica%20de%20Panam%C3%A1%203635%2C%20San%20Isidro%2015036!5e0!3m2!1sen!2spe!4v1652844514162!5m2!1sen!2spe"
      width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
    <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/972188609815912449/976353955137343548/final_edificio.png" height="450" alt="">
  </div>
</section>
```

You also had a random extra closing `</a>` which I removed to make the markup valid.

Comment: Still not working, I just updated the code an you can see the whole HTML5 code here: https://codeshare.io/EBQQvo search ```<div class="flex-container">``` to get the map and picture code line.

Comment: There is no `<div class="flex-container"` in the link to code you provided. The problem must not be in this code. Because you can see from the snippet I provided for you that it is working as expected.

Comment: @Kilian Did you try removing the random `</a>` you had in your code? As suggested in my solution.

Comment: Yes, now its:

```<button class="btn btn-rounded btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Contáctanos</button>```

but still not working...

Comment: Also in the link I provided, the code it's in line 381.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bqle.jpg Works like a charm, even with your full code.

Comment: This is the website: http://pruebalanding.aulavirtual.acti.edu.pe/ it's not working not sure why...

Comment: @Kilian https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjSeN.jpg Last time I am going to comment just to keep reiterating the same thing I initially told you in my solution. CLEARLY, it works. Look at the screenshot. It's on you now to apply what I have told you.

Comment: @Kilian Able to get it to work?